# Add and remove UIImage from array in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimage

My app loads pictures in to the `UICollectionView` from iPhone gallery, Facebook and Instagram. Everything works fine but I have a small problem and I'm stuck.. The user can selected some of the images (from gallery, Fb, or IG) and load it to the another `ViewController`, With Facebook and Instagram the thing is simple because when user selected the images I load the URL to the array and when he deselect and just simply remove this URL from an array. The problem appears with an iPhone gallery. He can selected the images but he can not unsealed (I just can't remove a deselected image from the array).

This is the code for ViewController which is responsible for selecting and "deselecting" images from gallery.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    _selectedCells.add(indexPath)
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

    CounterManager.addPhotos()

    // These lines should add selected images to the array
    let asset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.row)
    let image = getUIImage(asset: asset)

    tempUIImageArray.append(image!)
    CounterManager.updateText(label: numberOfPickslabel)
    GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages.append(image!)


    if CounterManager.flag && CounterManager.counter >= 20 {
        present(CounterManager.alert(), animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else if CounterManager.flag == false && CounterManager.counter >= 40 {

        present(CounterManager.alert(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    collectionView.allowsSelection = true
    _selectedCells.remove(indexPath)
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    CounterManager.subPhotos()
    CounterManager.updateText(label: numberOfPickslabel)

    //These lines should remove images from the Array
    let asset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.row)
    let image = getUIImage(asset: asset)
    GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages = GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages.filter({$0 != image})
}
```

`GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages` is the global array for all the images (from gallery, Fb and IG).

The `getUIImage` is the method that converts `PHAsset` to `UIImage`

It seems that the selected and deselected image keeps changing some data. Below is a picture were I am selecting and deselecting the same image. I do not understand why it's happening..

[image]
I will be very grateful for all kind of help.
Thanks M.

Comment: what's the problem, why cannot you just remove the image?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question.

Comment: so you are trying to say that the problem is that the image from gallery does not get deselected?

Comment: Yes this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in comparing the image with the other to filter and remove the the deselected one here

```
 GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages = GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages.filter({$0 != image})
```

This can't be valid as image comparison is a way far from that , so you should associate each image with id or index to select or deselect according to that

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an actual `UIImage` out of the gallery and storing it in an array, not a unique text reference to the image location. I suspect this is something to do with the way `GalleryManager` loads images (because you're just comparing raw image data using `!=`, which doesn't work). But without seeing the code, I can't be sure.

I'd suggest using `ALAssetsLibrary` instead to get a reference URL to the image, and storing that in your array - this way you can guarantee that the image ref is unique, and you can easily remove it from your array.

Some side notes:

1. Storing binary data in an array is going to eat memory like crazy. It is not efficient, and you're going to run into problems (especially on older devices).
2. This code is likely to break whenever `asset` is nil:

   ```
   let image = getUIImage(asset: asset)
   tempUIImageArray.append(image!)
   ```

   This is a good candidate for `guard` or `if x let`:

   ```
   guard let image = getUIImage(asset: asset) else { return }
   tempUIImageArray.append(image)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for side notes, I changed it to the guard let statement. Is it ok to store PHAssetes in array and after clicking the confirmation button convert it to the UIImage? Because it seems like it works.

Comment: It works, but again, that’s gonna be a major drain on memory because each object is very large.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you compare two different `UIImage` instances, even though they are created from the same data, they won't be evaluated as the same.

Instead of keeping the selected images in a separate array (`GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages`), keep just the original array of images, and to detect which are selected, create an array of selected images' indexes (e.g., `GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImagesIndixes`) in the original array of images. That way you can have access to the selected images by accessing the original array through the index and you want have problem of comparing two `UIImage`s, because you will work witn `Int`s.

**UPDATE**

Based on the `UIImage` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage):

> **Comparing Images**
>
> The `isEqual(_:)` method is the only reliable way to determine whether two images contain the same image data. The image objects you create may be different from each other, even when you initialize them with the same cached image data. The only way to determine their equality is to use the `isEqual(_:)` method, which compares the actual image data. Listing 1 illustrates the correct and incorrect ways to compare images.
>
> Listing 1
>
> Comparing two images
>
> ```
> let image1 = UIImage(named: "MyImage")
> let image2 = UIImage(named: "MyImage") 
> if image1 != nil && image1!.isEqual(image2) {
>     // Correct. This technique compares the image data correctly.
> } 
> if image1 == image2 {
>     // Incorrect! Direct object comparisons may not work.
> }
> ```

Therefore your problem might be also solvable by swapping comparisong using `==` and `!=` with `.isEqual(_:)`.

Change:

```
GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages = GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages.filter({$0 != image})
```

To:

```
GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages = GalleryManager.selectedGalleryImages.filter({ !($0.isEqual(image)) })
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what about PHAssetes? Is it ok to store them into the array and after clicking the confirmation button convert it to the UIImage?

Comment: @Matt199 I guess so.. but I would probably store `UIImage`s instead.. why phassets?

Comment: @Matt199 did you solve it? I just stumbled upon a note in documentation that probably explains why did this happen to you..

Comment: To be honest I just store images from PHAssetes after picked cause user can only pick 20 images, and I moved to the next part of an app, but thanks to you maybe it will be much easer and effective. Thank you Milan, I will check this later today/tomorrow and I will let you know! And ofc will accept the answer :)